# UITableViewCell does not select in editing mode sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, multipleselection

My UITableViewCell selection is none, and when I set the UITableView to edit mode, I change the selection of all visible cells to default in a loop. It works good, but sometimes some of them doesn't select I don't know why.

```
var IsEditingMode: Bool {

    get {
        return self.tableView.isEditing
    } set {

        self.tableView.setEditing(newValue, animated: true)

        for i in self.tableView.visibleCells {
            i.selectionStyle = newValue ? .default : .none
            let cell = i as! CheckCell
            if cell.isExpanded && newValue {
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                cell.isExpanded = false
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you test in a device?

Comment: @RazibMollick Yes I have this problem on simulators and my devices too